# Highlight important words/lines permanently

Tags: highlight

I'm working on a plain text file. I'd like to highlight important words or lines so that they stand out. How can I change background color and/or text color for selected text or word under cursor?

**UPDATE**

By permanent I meant that the highlighting lasts and saved when closing the document. I'd like to highlight different words and lines one after another.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/colorizing-plain-text

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to highlight arbitrary words temporary there is no builtin/easy way to make it permanent -- it is plain text. I mean, without injecting additional text/chars into your file.

If you are OK there might be some stuff inserted then try txtfmt plugin https://github.com/bpstahlman/txtfmt

Comment: And of course it would be marked as duplicate, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

#### colorful, ephemeral or semi-permanent

Adding arbitrary highlights for text fragments can be done via [`:help :match`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%3Amatch) (and `:2match`, `:3match`, generically with [`matchadd()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchadd%28%29)). These built-in commands provide the basic functionality, but for a great user experience, more stuff is needed (like helpful mappings that mirror the build-in `/` and `*` commands, `:autocmd`s that apply the highlightings not just in the current window, maybe persistence across settings. For that, a plugin is needed.

My [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) is one of those. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.) The highlighting (patterns and colors) won't be part of the buffer; best you could do is storing these as annotations in a *modeline*-like comment.

#### really permanent

If you instead really want complete permanency:

- For a few keywords, a *syntax extension* could work. Many syntaxes already have a common highlighting of `TODO`, `FIXME`, and similar keywords.
- There are many "enriched text" formats; *Markdown* is very famous (and also used here on Stack Overflow); some languages already allow embedding inside comments or other blocks; for others this could be grafted on via my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168). You'd be limited to a few common formatting styles (like **bold** and *italic*), though, or have to insert big ugly markup (like `<font>` tags).